# auto completion of syntax for HTML or PHP in Notepadqq?

Tags: software-recommendation, notepadqq

I'm looking extension for **notepadqq** text editor of   **Syntax** auto complete.
so is this extension available on notepadqq 
if yes where i can find it ?